# split list into sublists according to variable string and variable block length

Tags: python, string, split, sublist

I have a list of strings:

```
['splitter001','stringA','stringB','splitter_1234','stringC']
```

and I want my end result to be:

```
[ ['splitter001','stringA','stringB'] , ['splitter_1234','stringC'] ]
```

The splitter dividers are not identical strings.

I've tried to .find the 'splitter' if the element index > 0, and then delete the indexes [:2nd splitter] and append the first group into a new list, but this doesn't work properly.

I am iterating a for loop over all the strings and it doesn't work for the second group so I can get:

```
[ ['splitter001','stringA','stringB'] ] as my new list, but the second group is missing.
```

I've read many answers on this topic and the closest solution was to use:

```
[list(x[1]) for x in itertools.groupby(myList, lambda x: x=='#') if not x[0]]
```

but I do not understand this syntax... I've read on groupby and intertools but I'm not sure this is helpful for my situations.

Comment: Not sure if you can achieve that just by using `groupby`..a solution like `[list(group) for _, group in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x.startswith('splitter'))]` would keep the splitter* elements in separate sublists..but interesting problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do this with `groupby`. We tell `groupby` to look for strings that start with 'splitter'. This creates two kinds of groups: strings that start with 'splitter', and all the other strings. Eg,

```
from itertools import groupby

data = ['splitter001','stringA','stringB','splitter_1234','stringC']

for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda s: s.startswith('splitter')):
    print(k, list(g))
```

**output**

```
True ['splitter001']
False ['stringA', 'stringB']
True ['splitter_1234']
False ['stringC']
```

So we can put those groups into two lists and then zip them together to make the final list.

```
from itertools import groupby

data = ['splitter001','stringA','stringB','splitter_1234','stringC']

head = []
tail = []
for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda s: s.startswith('splitter')):
    if k:
        head.append(list(g))
    else:
        tail.append(list(g))

out = [u+v for u, v in zip(head, tail)]
print(out)
```

**output**

```
[['splitter001', 'stringA', 'stringB'], ['splitter_1234', 'stringC']]
```

Here's a more compact way to do the same thing, using a list of lists to store the head and tail lists:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = ['splitter001','stringA','stringB','splitter_1234','stringC']
results = [[], []]
for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda s: s.startswith('splitter')):
    results[k].append(list(g))

out = [v+u for u, v in zip(*results)]
print(out)
```

**output**

```
[['splitter001', 'stringA', 'stringB'], ['splitter_1234', 'stringC']]
```

---

If you want to print each sublist on a separate line, the simple way is to do it with a `for` loop instead of creating the `out` list.

```
for u, v in zip(*results):
    print(v + u)
```

**output**

```
['splitter001', 'stringA', 'stringB']
['splitter_1234', 'stringC']
```

Another way is to convert the sublists to strings and then join them together with newlines to create one big string.

```
print('\n'.join([str(v + u) for u, v in zip(*results)]))
```

---

This final variation stores both kinds of groups into a single iterator object. I think you'll agree that the previous versions are easier to read. :)

```
it = iter(list(g) for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda s: s.startswith('splitter')))
out = [u+v for u, v in zip(it, it)]
```

Comment: Hi, from a first reading it seems this might work, but can you explain a couple of things:
1 - what does the list in list(g) refer to? just the fact that g is a list?
2 - what is out= ? is that a variable that stores the results? why not just use results itself..?

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky **1** The groups that `groupby` produces are iterators, so we need to convert those iterators to proper lists. See what gets printed with my 1st example if you replace the `list(g)` call with `g`. **2** Sure, I could have re-cycled `results` instead of using the name `out`. I figured that using a separate name would make it clear that they are 2 different lists, with different structures.

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky You may find this article interesting:  [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)

Comment: Thanks. I tried it with your:

for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda s: s.startswith('splitter')):
    results[k].append(list(g))

solution, but two things:
1 - the output I get is [['splitter001', 'stringA', 'stringB', 'splitter_1234'],  ['stringC']]
do I need to append the list in a different way? I tried it exactly as you wrote it.

2 - when I try to print the entire results list with:

def print_dataset(dataset):
  for each in dataset:
    print each,


it doesn't separate the elements with line breaks

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky **1** Sorry! I made a copy & paste error in that version: it had `u+v` instead of `v+u`. That happened because I had all 3 versions in the same script. **2** I'll add some more code to show how to print the sublists on separate lines in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

get indices of `startswith('splitter')` elements, then slice the list at those indices

```
sl = ['splitter001','stringA','stringB','splitter_1234','stringC']

si = [i for i, e in enumerate(sl) if e.startswith('splitter')]
[sl[i:j] for i, j in zip(si, si[1:] + [len(sl)])]

Out[66]: [['splitter001', 'stringA', 'stringB'], ['splitter_1234', 'stringC']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using a `for` loop, as you mentioned you tried, that handles the case of the second group:

```
# define list of strings for input
strings = ['splitter001','stringA','stringB','splitter_1234','stringC']
split_strings = []  # this is going to hold the final output
current_list = []  # this is a temporary list

# loop over strings in the input
for s in strings:
    if 'splitter' in s:
        # if current_list is not empty
        if current_list:
            split_strings.append(current_list)  # append to output
            current_list = []  # reset current_list
    current_list.append(s)

# outside of the loop, append the leftover strings (if any)
if current_list:
    split_strings.append(current_list)
```

The key here is that you do one more append at the end, outside of your loop, to capture the last group.

Output:

```
[['splitter001', 'stringA', 'stringB'], ['splitter_1234', 'stringC']]
```

**EDIT**: Adding explanation of code.

We create a temp variable `current_list` to hold each list that we will append to the final output `split_strings`.

Loop over the strings in the input. For each string `s`, check if it contains `'splitter'`. If it does AND the `current_list` is not empty, this means that we've hit the next delimiter. Append `current_list` to the output and clear it out so we can begin collecting items for the next set of strings.

After this check, append the current string to `current_list`. This works because we cleared it out (setting it equal to `[]`) after we found a delimiter.

At the end of the list, we append whatever is leftover to the output, if anything.

Comment: I don't understand the logic here. First you create a placeholder empty list of every string splitter you find and then you place the string there, but I can't see how the other strings get into the current_list... ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

first get the `from to` index numbers when `splitter` appeared then just chuck the list according to those index:

```
sl = ['splitter001','stringA','stringB','splitter_1234','stringC']

si = [index for index, value in enumerate(sl) if value.startswith('splitter')]
for i in range(0,len(si),1):

    slice=si[i:i+2]
    if len(slice)==2:
        print(sl[slice[0]:slice[1]])
    else:
        print(sl[slice[0]:])
```

output:

```
['splitter001', 'stringA', 'stringB']
['splitter_1234', 'stringC']
```